# Is or was in this case?

Tags: past-tense

> I have bought many records from you and the last one I ordered a long time ago **was** the 10 inches of xxxx. I worry a bit because this vinyl is no longer advertised. Have you cancelled it? Or is it already sold out that there is no point in advertising it now? Please could you keep me informed.

What is better here "was"or "is"? I think " was" is better because this record was ordered a long time ago so it happens to the past. As this record is not out at the time of writing may be "is" can fit too.

Comment: You ordered/bought the record in the past, so **was**. Aside, phonograph records are usually described as 7-inch, 10-inch or 12-inch.

Comment: Saying "As this record is not out at the time of writing" makes it unclear what you want to write. Are you ordering a new release, but mentioning that you are a previous customer?

Comment: the next sentence is "  I worry a bit because this vinyl is no longer advertised. Have you cancelled it ?or is it  already sold out  that  there  is no point in advertising it now ?

Please could you keep me informed  "

Comment: It's still not clear. Are you trying to say that you are a loyal customer who ordered a new record some time ago, but it has not yet been delivered? If so, you can say "I ordered the 10-inch "*Album name*" on [date] but it hasn't arrived yet."

Comment: First I want to know why the record is not out yet and I am  afraid that it was cancelled. In fact I want to know what is happening to this record and  my order  and remind the label that I am a loyal customer

Comment: If you a) change the sentence around as I suggested, and b) don't muddle the sentence with the fact that you have previously placed orders in the past it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The record **is** in your possession, but the order/purchase **was** in the past, and it's that action you are speaking about, so 'was' is the correct tense.

Example:

> This **is** my favourite record. It **was** the first one I bought.

Comment: No, this record is not  my position  that is why I thought that "is"  is  another correct solution .

Comment: @user5577 Ok, I was writing as if it were an example to demonstrate the difference between the tenses as I thought the present nature of the item was what was possibly causing the confusion.

Comment: so" is "not possible in my example